# Ubuntu Intermittent internet and stable local connection

Tags: ubuntu, networking, network-interface, internet, troubleshooting

I have a server running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I can connect to it via SSH from any other computer on my network no problem. I can also access the services it has running from my network. Unfortunately its internet connection is intermittent. If I try to ping google its a toss up if it'll work. It'll be perfectly good for 5 minutes then just stop for a similar amount of time.

any ideas? To me it seems unlikely to be a cable issue since I can connect via SSH/Streaming service/Remote Desktop no problem. Doesn't seem to be a broader issue with the internet since all other devices have a solid connection. This server also used to have a solid connection until a couple weeks ago.

thanks